# Cannot change permissions in Google Chrome Linux

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-connect, linux-mint-19

I want to change camera permissions in Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) but it is disabled. (website is Adobe Connect)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXVCP.png)

OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon

I can change the permissions in Firefox. So can you help me how to do that in chrome?

Comment: and is that linux mint computer a virtualbox instance?

Comment: @ruud No. Is that related to permissions?

Comment: in virtualbox, you have to give permission for use of the camera from the host. if you forget that, you get the same message as you did. But that is not the case in this situation....